# Ionic 'Xcode Message '' '

Tags: xcode, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am now developing IONIC app and have installed it to my iPhone, using Xcode. In Browser I can fetch more than 200 data and list them, but my Xcode shows me some error message like

> Received memory warning.

when running it on my iPhone.

I have searched for many web sites and I think that it is a kind of 'memory leakage' problem, but I cannot find the solution to solve it. I appreciate someone can give me some hints.

Service:

```
    getWordsByWord: function(maxWord) {
        return $firebaseArray(ref.child('words').orderByChild('number').startAt(0).endAt(maxWord));
    }
```

Controller:

```
    home.words = [];

    maxWord = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('maxWord'));
    maxWord = maxWord === null? 200 : maxWord;

    abstract = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('abstract'));
    abstract = abstract === null? true : abstract;

    concrete = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('concrete'));
    concrete = concrete === null? true : concrete;

    Auth.getWordsByWord(maxWord).$loaded().then(function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var item = data[i];

            if ((item.classification == 'abstract' && abstract) || (item.classification == 'concrete' && concrete)) {
                home.words.push(item);
            }
        }

        Like.allLikesByUser(currentUid).$loaded().then(function(likesList) {
            home.words = _.filter(home.words, function(obj) {
                return _.isEmpty(_.where(likesList, {$id: obj.$id}));
            });
        });

        if (home.words.length > 0) {
            home.currentIndex = home.words.length - 1;
            home.currentCardUid = home.words[home.currentIndex].$id;
        }

        $scope.hide();

    });
```

When I change the number of fetching data from 200 to 100 like as follows,

```
maxWord = maxWord === null? 100 : maxWord;
```

my App does not crash.

when I change

```
maxWord = maxWord === null? 200 : maxWord;
```

my App crash...

I have 200 data in my Firebase database in 'words' node, and each word has number(key) and 1 to 200(value).
So when running this app, I fetch the data from 1 to 100 or 1 to 200.

I would appreciate if somebody can answer to my question.

Comment: What are you using the data for? If you are showing in a list or something you should use some sort og paging or infinite scroller...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I am using 'ionic-ion-tinder-cards' module and using those data for kind of Japanese-English dictionary which shows each image and each word on the screen. If you already know the word, you can swipe to right, and if not yet, you can swipe to left. Could you give me some hints that enable me to use paging or infinite scroll using 'ionic-ion-tinder-cards' module ? Do you know some tips ??